# How to break and If Else statement vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to have user select device from comboBox and click the button. However, when they click button... MessageBox shows but also proceeds the button click. How do I stop the button click from continuing until user selects device?

```
Private Sub EstablishConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EstablishConnection.Click

        Dim DeviceValidFalg As Boolean = True

        If DeviceDropDownList.Text = "USB" Then
            DeviceName = "USB Adapter"
        ElseIf DeviceDropDownList.Text = "USB1" Then
            DeviceName = "USB HDMI"
        ElseIf DeviceDropDownList.Text = "USB2" Then
            DeviceName = "HGCV"
        ElseIf DeviceDropDownList.Text = String.Empty Then
            DeviceValidFalg = False
            MessageBox.Show("Select a valid device")
        End If
```

Comment: vb.net and vbscript are different languages. Choose one (I think it's vb.net)

Comment: Use `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @CoderCharmander thank you, the Exit Sub is what I needed after the MessageBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the logic to match the business need - that a bad input must be handled differently.

For example (one way of doing this) you could wrap the two paths in a `If-Then-Else` block:

```
Private Sub EstablishConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EstablishConnection.Click

        Dim DeviceValidFalg As Boolean = True

        If DeviceDropDownList.Text <> String.Empty Then
            Select Case DeviceDropDownList.Text
                Case "USB"
                    DeviceName = "USB Adapter"
                Case "USB1"
                    DeviceName = "USB HDMI"
                Case "USB2"
                    DeviceName = "HGCV"
                Case Else
                    ' Some other code of your choosing here
            End Select
            ' The rest of your logic here
        Else
            DeviceValidFalg = False
            MessageBox.Show("Select a valid device")
        End If
```

I prefer `Case` over `ElseIf` for simple checks (like you have here) because it is cleaner, easier to read and thus easier to maintain.

Another approach could be to `Exit Sub` early (as noted by @CoderCharmander in comments):

```
Private Sub EstablishConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EstablishConnection.Click

        Dim DeviceValidFalg As Boolean = True

        If DeviceDropDownList.Text = String.Empty Then
            DeviceValidFalg = False
            MessageBox.Show("Select a valid device")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Select Case DeviceDropDownList.Text
            Case "USB"
                DeviceName = "USB Adapter"
            Case "USB1"
                DeviceName = "USB HDMI"
            Case "USB2"
                DeviceName = "HGCV"
            Case Else
                ' Some other code of your choosing here
        End Select
        ' The rest of your logic here
```

The best refactoring is to ensure they cannot click the button (disable it) until they have valid input! That is, enable the button based on the values of the various user input controls.

**Addendum** (from @JohnPete22 in the comments):

`If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceDropDownList.Text)` instead of `DeviceDropDownList.Text <> String.Empty` better uses the VB.Net `String` construct and allows for the case where the string is not `Trim`med from the input. Of course, remove the `Not` for the `=` in my second example.

Comment: Only thing I'd update is ````DeviceDropDownList.Text <> String.Empty```` to ````If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceDropDownList.Text)```` especially since you're not trimming the text from the textbox.

Comment: @AJD Thank you for suggesting the `Case`. After playing around with it, I like it better as well. That `Exit Sub` did the trick as well from @CoderCharmander